# java reflection: getMethods function not showing a method

Tags: java, reflection

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test
{
     public static void main(String s[]) throws ClassNotFoundException
     {
        Class cls = Class.forName("Test");
        System.out.println("Class is "+cls);
        Method[] mtds = cls.getMethods();
        System.out.println("Methods are "+Arrays.deepToString(mtds));  // not having all methods
    }

    void reflectionTestMethod()
    {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

Output is

> Class is class Test
>
> Methods are [public static void
>   Test.main(java.lang.String[]) throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException,
>   public final void java.lang.Object.wait() throws
>   java.lang.InterruptedException, public final native void
>   java.lang.Object.wait(long) throws java.lang.InterruptedException,
>   public final void java.lang.Object.wait(long,int) throws
>   java.lang.InterruptedException, public boolean
>   java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object), public java.lang.String
>   java.lang.Object.toString(), public native int
>   java.lang.Object.hashCode(), public final native java.lang.Class
>   java.lang.Object.getClass(), public final native void
>   java.lang.Object.notify(), public final native void
>   java.lang.Object.notifyAll()]

Why is **reflectionTestMethod()** not available in the output ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`getMethods()` returns public methods (as it states in its Javadoc)

Try `getDeclaredMethods()` instead or make the method public.

BTW, you can do:

```
Class cls = Test.class;
System.out.println("Class is " + cls);
for(Method method : cls.getDeclaredMethods())
    System.out.println(method);
```

Comment: +1 for getDeclaredMethods. I'll try to give you your 100,000th point ;-)

Comment: @assylias I think you just did. ;) I try to give 500 point bounties to my questions, but even so...

Comment: Too late to take it back, I am still over. :D

Answer (score 4):

Because that method is not public. The [javadoc states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods%28%29) (emphasis mine):

> Returns an array containing Method objects reflecting all the **public member methods** of the class or interface represented by this Class object